# window.focus is redirecting without query params

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, navigation, passport.js

Im working passport based authentication 
problem is redirection is working but not with desired  query parameters ie. is **accessToken** and **redirectAfterAuthentication** 
I redirecting to frontend route but without query params
Expected result : `frontend_url?accessToken=something&redirectAfterAuthentication=something` 
But result is I'm only redirecting to `frontend_url`

If I write `window.location.href = frontend_url?accessToken=<%= accessToken %>&&redirectAfterAuthentication=<%= redirectAfterAuthentication %>` it works fine but on browser back I get same ejs file rendering, and I want to avoid that.

for frontend im perfoming these

```
window.open(`backend_url`, "_blank","unique_tab");
```

and from backend after succesful login redirection code in **ejs**(Node.js) file is as follows

```
window.focus('fronted_url?accessToken=<%= accessToken %>&&redirectAfterAuthentication=<%= redirectAfterAuthentication %>',"unique_tab");
          window.close();
```

Comment: I think we need more information, like where does the `.focus` code run, how do you replace the parameters, etc. It could be a number of things.

Comment: @filipe this code is written in ejs file which get rendered by node, If I write window.location.href = frontend_url it works fine but on browser back I get same ejs file rendering.